# How could I add my deep learning model to a web application?

Tags: python, machine-learning, web-applications, computer-vision, web-deployment

I am planning to create a ml model the recognizes some stuff in real time video, it will be a deep learning model, What I would like to know is how could I apply that model into my web app and what should I use? I want to use the cam of the computer and the model to recognize some patterns.

I did not made anything yet but I am plannig the project. any ideas is appreciated. I know streamlit and gradio, but i would like to use node, any framework like react or django, flask etc. any idea is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers will vary depending on the details of the project. For example if you want build basic project, you can use basic html, css and javascript for Frontend but if you need state management between the pages, you can use React.

You can use FastAPI or Flask for accessing model prediction and send to Frontend, you can search like this "Deploy Machine Learning Model using Flask" on the Internet. If you want to access webcam you can use VideoCapture in OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks I have a pre-trained model. This model is sign language recognition. My web app will be a videocall web app, and I want to suggestions of how could I send the video from the videocalls to the model which will be hosted into a API, also i consider transform my model to a tensorflowjs but i want to know any idea of sending the video of the videochats to the model api. Thanks for you help

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never used TensorFlow.js. I don't know about it. On the other hand, you can refer to this article on how to enable API communication: [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-a-pre-trained-keras-model-with-opencv-and-flask-86c9dab76a9c) and maybe your model will be slow for processing many images which are coming the webcam consider this.